# How hard is it to set up a Google App Engine app?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I found a simple Google App Engine open source app which I'd like to play with. Coming from Objective-C my Java knowledge is limited.

Is there a tutorial that walks through the entire process of how to create a simple Google App Engine app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend python personally, as you can literally just edit the pages on the fly, press refresh and see the effects immediately in the browser.

If I could give you two pointers though

1) Every action needs to be an http request - keep that in mind when you start and it will make things easy for you

2) Forget SQL. And use the relationships between classes to navigate between them.

Comment: That means I don't have to get used to Eclipse on the mac? So I could just use a text editor to edit python scripts?

Comment: I would only use eclipse now if I had no other option. It's good .. but I just don't get on with it sometimes. You are right - you can use any editor you want. Even emacs ...

Answer (score 3):

did you saw this.. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/ This is the one i referred when i started with it..  or probably this one for a hello world program http://googcloudlabs.appspot.com/codelabexercise0.html